Polars-python: is_in for lazyframe TypeError
I am getting the following TypeError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/my/path/my_project/src/my_project/exploration/mre_lazyframe_error.py", line 39, in <module>
    current.with_columns(pl.col("foo_bar").is_in(reference["foo_bar"]))
  File "/my/path/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/my_project-p95GORRi-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/polars/lazyframe/frame.py", line 619, in __getitem__
    raise TypeError(msg)
TypeError: 'LazyFrame' object is not subscriptable (aside from slicing)

MRE
import numpy as np
import polars as pl

num_rows = 10000
ids = np.arange(num_rows)
foo_bar = np.random.randint(1, 101, num_rows)

current = pl.LazyFrame(
    {
        "id": ids,
        "foo_bar": foo_bar,
    }
)
reference = pl.LazyFrame(
    {
        "id": ids,
        "foo_bar": np.random.randint(
            1, 101, num_rows
        ),  # different random numbers for 'reference'
    }
)

current.with_columns(
    pl.col("foo_bar").is_in(reference["foo_bar"]).name.suffix("_avail"),
)

current.with_columns(pl.col("foo_bar").is_in(reference["foo_bar"]))

As far as I understand it this should be possible (is_in docs).
When I do it in eager it runs through without any error.
However I would preferably compute everything in lazy.
Is there anyway to make this work?

Subscription of DataFrame return series, but subscription (or get_column() method) is not implemented for LazyFrame (what would it even return?). There is a closed issue where it was decided that it's not going to be implemented.
If amount of distinct values in reference frame is not large (as in your case), you could collect the values and convert them to series:
(
    current
    .with_columns(
        pl.col("foo_bar").is_in(
            reference.select("foo_bar").unique().collect().to_series()
        ).name.suffix("_avail")
    )
)

In general such operations are usually much faster with joins, though. To get all the rows where foo_bar exists in reference you could use pl.LazyFrame.join with how="semi":


semi
Returns rows from the left table that have a match in the right table.



current.join(reference, on="foo_bar", how="semi")

